Power Automate Time Zone Issue
I have created a Power Automate flow which triggers When a new email is received and
Based on the time it is received I need to send an automated response to the sender at which time we will respond to the requirement based on certain calculations. However, facing some issues in the Email Received time. ( Time Zone Related )
Auto Response Email
In the email box received time is mentioned correctly as follows. And the time Zone settings are also correct 
Power Automate Flow As follows
To make to time calculation correct,
I have used the convert time zone option.
But Still, in the trailing email body, it shows the wrong time.
Could you give me a lead to overcome this issue?

the email output will have UTC time. why dont you just add 'x' hours as per your timezone difference.
